# Share Partials/Components between 2 Plugins

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, october-partial

Is there a way to access partials from another component or another plugin?

I have a modal component showing some sort of message. Now I have another component showing a complex form in a modal dialog. They reside in 2 plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, inside of a plugin component you can access partials from both another component in the same plugin (you'd setup a shared partial), and components and partials from other plugins.

For accessing shared partials between components in the same plugin, [see this section of the docs.](http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#component-partials):

> Multiple components can share partials by placing the partial file in
>   a directory called `components/partials`. The partials found in this
>   directory are used as a fallback when the usual component partial
>   cannot be found. For example, a shared partial located in
>   `/plugins/acme/blog/components/partials/shared.htm` can be displayed on
>   the page by any component using:
>
> ```
> {% partial '@shared' %}
> ```

For accessing components or partials from another plugin inside of your component plugin, see the following examples of the `Foo` and `Bar` plugins:

`plugins/montanabanana/foo/Plugin.php:`

```php
<?php namespace MontanaBanana\Foo;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public function registerComponents()
    {
        return [
            'MontanaBanana\Foo\Components\Thud' => 'thud'
        ];
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }
}
```

`plugins/montanabanana/foo/components/Thud.php`

```php
<?php

namespace MontanaBanana\Foo\Components;

class Thud extends \Cms\Classes\ComponentBase
{
    public function componentDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Thud Component',
            'description' => ''
        ];
    }
}
```

`plugins/montanabanana/foo/components/thud/default.htm`

```
<pre>Thud component, default.htm</pre>
```

`plugins/montanabanana/foo/components/thud/partial.htm`

```
<pre>This is the thud partial</pre>
```

Ok, so we have setup the Foo plugin that registers a Thud component. That component has some basic default markup in it as well as a partial in the component folder. Now, let's setup another plugin that has a component `Grunt` which can use this component and partial `Thud` from `Foo`:

`plugins/montanabanana/bar/Plugin.php`

```php
<?php namespace MontanaBanana\Bar;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    // We should require the plugin we are pulling from
    public $require = ['MontanaBanana.Foo'];

    public function registerComponents()
    {
        return [
            'MontanaBanana\Bar\Components\Grunt' => 'grunt'
        ];
    }

    public function registerSettings()
    {
    }
}
```

`plugins/montanabanana/bar/components/grunt/default.htm`

```
<pre>Grunt component, default.htm</pre>

{% component 'thud' %}

{% partial 'thud::partial' %}
```

Note that in the above component default markup file for the Grunt component in Bar, we have called both the Thud component and the `partial.htm` partial from the Thud component.

We're not quite done though, and I am pretty sure it has to be done this way (though there may be a more elegant way I don't know about), but we have define both components on the page we want to call this all from:

`themes/your-theme/pages/example.htm`

```
title = "Example"
url = "/example"

[grunt]
[thud]
==
{% component 'grunt' %}
```

The output of which is:

```
<pre>Grunt component, default.htm</pre>
<pre>Thud component, default.htm</pre>
<pre>This is the thud partial</pre>
```

I don't fully understand what you're asking in the second part of your question, but hopefully the above helps you solve it.